# How do I print custom user fields?

Tags: theming, 8

I am trying to customize the authored by information for all of my nodes that prints the User First and Last Name, which are custom fields on the User Profile.

1. I copied the node.html.twig template into my theme
2. I added the following code to load the user information in my preprocess function

   ```
   function blend_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

   // Load the current user.
   $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());

   // get field data from that user
   $firstname = $user->get('field_first_name')->value;
   $lastname = $user->get('field_last_name')->value;

   // some default getters include
   $email = $user->get('mail')->value;
   $name = $user->get('name')->value;
   $uid= $user->get('uid')->value;

   }
   ```
3. I added this code to node.html.twig

   ```
   {{ title_prefix }}   {% if not page %}
   <h2{{ title_attributes }}>
     <a href="{{ url }}" rel="bookmark">{{ label }}</a>
   </h2>   {% endif %}   {{ title_suffix }}

   {% if display_submitted %}

   <div class="posted">

       <div class="services-icon">
         {{ content.field_services }}
       </div> 


     {{ author_picture }}

     <div{{ author_attributes }}>
       {% trans %}Submitted by {{ firstname }} {{ lastname }} on {{ date|date("m/d/Y") }}{% endtrans %}
       {{ metadata }}
     </div>
   </div>   {% endif %}
   {# We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later. #}   <div{{ content_attributes }}>
   {{ content|without('comment', 'links', 'field_tags', 'field_services') }}   </div>

   {% if content.field_tags|length and not is_front %}
   {{ content.field_tags }}   {% endif %}
   {{ content.links }}   {{ content.comment }} </article>
   ```

How do I make variables (mostly fields) from different entities available to print in different template files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming this information is from the user profile.

You could do the following

**blend.theme**

```
function blend_preprocess_node(&$variables){
    $node = $variables['node'];
    $variables['firstname'] = $node->getOwner()->field_first_name->value;
    $variables['lastname'] = $node->getOwner()->field_last_name->value;
}
```

From there you can use `{{ firstname }}` and `{{lastname}}` anywhere in your template.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but your solution just gave me white screen. Is there another example on how I would print information from the node Author?

Comment: Oopss.. the `$node = $variables['node'];` need to be inside of the preprocess function. Sorry, I have fixed in my answer.

Comment: You rock sir!!!   

For future reference.  When looking to get access variables from other entities, where would I search in the D8 API for the correct functions?

Comment: "D8 API for the correct functions"... hahaha... I do not know. I know this because I'm working on contrib theme. And I ask a similar question before so I have plenty of examples in my working theme.

Comment: hahah thanks sir!  that is awesome :) Well I just added yours to my Dropbucket.  Its a cool place for Drupal snippets http://dropbucket.org/node/7235

Comment: @kaleemclarkson if you add use type hinting then your IDE will be able to help you guess the available methods on an object.

Comment: @Eyal

I mostly use sublime text 2. Is there a specific plugin that I need to make it work more like an traditional IDE?

Comment: @kaleemclarkson I don't know. I only use sublime for small projects. You should upgrade to an IDE.

Comment: Does someone know how to get the isolated path to th profile? In order to fill an <a href= …> to wrap around the name. Would $node->getOwner()->link_path->value; do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me on Drupal version 8.3.4 and more. Actually the `$node = $variables['node']` didn't work so I found out the following method to make it work.

On the .theme file (in this example blend.theme), I used the following code.

```php
function blend_preprocess_node(&$variables){
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  $variables['firstname'] = $node->getOwner()->field_first_name->value;
  $variables['lastname'] = $node->getOwner()->field_last_name->value;
}
```